# how to handle "automatic scroll" and "manual scroll" in a viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created an image slideshow for my app
but i face a problem

I have a `ViewPager` and 4 `Fragment` as slide
 and for automatic scroll i write this method :

```
public void autoScroll(Boolean autoScroll){
    this.autoScroll=autoScroll;
    if (autoScroll){
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new pageSwitcher(), 0, 3000);
    }else{
        if (timer==null) return;
        timer.cancel();
        timer=null;
    }
}
```

which page switcher is somthing like this

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1);
```

now my problem is to handle user swipe and automatic scroll.
if user start swipe in specific time that next fragment is created by adapter (due the autoscroll request) i face this error

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already active


at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setInitialSavedState(Fragment.java:574)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:110)
at Views.XprojectSlider.SlidesAdapter.instantiateItem(SlidesAdapter.java:90)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:870)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:552)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:514)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:495)
at Views.XprojectSlider.XprojectImageSlider.nextPage(XprojectImageSlider.java:201)
at Views.XprojectSlider.XprojectImageSlider.access$500(XprojectImageSlider.java:42)
at Views.XprojectSlider.XprojectImageSlider$3.run(XprojectImageSlider.java:206)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

is there any flag to detect viewpager is going to change page so i stop touch event ?

or is there any why to realize next fragment is created and dont need to call instantiateItem method of adapter ?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider this library. It has cool animations. And it's also easy to integrate.